# How to de-import a Python module?

Tags: python

I am in the process of coding an app which has to get the metadata (author,version..etc) out of several modules (.py files) and display them.  The user selects a script and the script is executed.  (New scripts can be added and old ones be taken of from the target folder just like a plugin system).

Firstly I import a script and I take out the metadata, then I go for the next.
But I  want to de-import all the other modules except for the one that the user has selected.

How can I implement this?

I tried these

```
1. del module
2. del sys.modules['module']
```

The latter did not work.  I tried #python and got the answer that it was not good to de-import modules, but I want to know a clean way of implementing this.  Any ideas/suggestions would help.

Comment: There _is_ no clean way to deimport modules. Everything you're going to do is through hacks.

Comment: Get metadata by parsing the code using the `ast` module instead of importing them, as tools like [Epydoc](http://epydoc.sf.net), [PyDoctor](http://codespeak.net/~mwh/pydoctor/), and [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org) do.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think [this post](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2006-August/048596.html) should help you.

To secure the availability of this information (in case the link dies or something similar), below is the original message from the [tutor mailing list](http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/tutor):

---

On 8/14/06, Dick Moores  wrote:

> Actually, my question is, after using IDLE to do some importing of
> modules and initializing of variables, how to return it to it's
> initial condition without closing and reopening it.
>
> So, for example after I've done
>
> ```
> >>> import math, psyco
> >>> a = 4**23
> ```
>
> How can I wipe those out without closing IDLE?
> (I used to know how, but I've forgotten.)

Hi Dick,

Usually this entails removing from the "module registry and removing
references to it in the code.  If you have a *really* well used module (like
one with config parameters imported into every module), then you'll have an
additional step of removing it from every module.  Also, if you have use
"from psyco import ...", then you will not be able to free up the module and
the reference to the module easily (is it from that module, or imported from
a third module? see "if paranoid: code below).

The function below deletes a module by name from the Python interpreter, the
"paranoid" parameter is a list of variable names to remove from every other
module (supposedly being deleted with the module).  Be VERY careful with the
paranoid param; it could cause problems for your interpreter if your
functions and classes are named the same in different modules.  One common
occurrance of this is "error" for exceptions.  A lot of libraries have one
"catch-all" exception called "error" in the module.  If you also named your
exception "error" and decided to include that in the paranoid list... there
go a lot of other exception objects.

```
def delete_module(modname, paranoid=None):
    from sys import modules
    try:
        thismod = modules[modname]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError(modname)
    these_symbols = dir(thismod)
    if paranoid:
        try:
            paranoid[:]  # sequence support
        except:
            raise ValueError('must supply a finite list for paranoid')
        else:
            these_symbols = paranoid[:]
    del modules[modname]
    for mod in modules.values():
        try:
            delattr(mod, modname)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        if paranoid:
            for symbol in these_symbols:
                if symbol[:2] == '__':  # ignore special symbols
                    continue
                try:
                    delattr(mod, symbol)
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
```

Then you should be able to use this like:

```
delete_module('psyco')
```

or

```
delete_module('psyco', ['Psycho', 'KillerError'])
# only delete these symbols from every other module
# (for "from psyco import Psycho, KillerError" statements)
```

-Arcege

Comment: Can you summarize the contents here should that link ever die?

Comment: thanx for the link... but is there any other way to get the metadata other then importing.

Answer (score 7):

Suggestion: Import your modules dynamically using `__import__`

E.g.

```
module_list = ['os', 'decimal', 'random']
for module in module_list:
    x = __import__(module)
    print 'name: %s - module_obj: %s' % (x.__name__, x)
```

Will produce:

```
name: os - module_obj: <module 'os' from '/usr/lib64/python2.4/os.pyc'>
name: decimal - module_obj: <module 'decimal' from '/usr/lib64/python2.4/decimal.pyc'>
name: random - module_obj: <module 'random' from '/usr/lib64/python2.4/random.pyc'>
```

Though, this won't really remove it from the modules registry. The next time that it is imported, it won't re-read the package/module file and it won't execute it. To accomplish that, you can simply modify the above code snippet like this:

```
import sys
module_list = ['os', 'decimal', 'random', 'test1']
for module_name in module_list:
    x = __import__(module_name)
    print 'name: %s - module_obj: %s' % (x.__name__, x)
    del x
    sys.modules.pop(module_name)
```

Answer (score 7):

I recently found this post https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reloading-modules-python/ and so for Python 3.4 or later use

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(module)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this post has been out of date but I just encountered this issue and was struggling against it for the past few days. Now I came with a conclusion that can perfectly solve this issue. Please see the sample code below:

```
try:
    theMod = sys.modules['ModNeedToBeDel']   
except:
    theMod = None
if theMod:
    del sys.modules['ModNeedToBeDel']

#The extra try/except below is because I implemented the block in a module of a sub-package; this ModNeedToBeDel in my case was imported either by the toppest level Main code, or by the other sub-package modules. That's why I need two different try/except.

try:
    theMod = sys.modules['UpperFolder.ModNeedToBeDel']   
except:
    theMod = None
if theMod:
    del sys.modules['UpperFolder.ModNeedToBeDel']
import ModNeedToBeDel   # or UpperFolder.ModNeedToBeDel here
```

Note that `del sys.modules[theMod]` won't work, because it just deletes the reference, instead of the actual `ModNeedToBeDel`.

Hope this could help someone so that they won't have to struggle on this issue for several days!