# Using pip to install a program while running

Tags: python, plugins, pip

I have a program with plugin functionality and I don't want to install all the plugins from setup.py if I am not using them. They should only be installed when they are activated in the config of the main program.

Is it possible to install these programs using `pip` while running the main program?

Something like this:

```
try:
   if PLUGINNAME not installed:
      pip install PLUGINNAME
```

I know its possible to use `os.system` to force console input but that seems really bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a by trying to import the module. If the module is not installed an ImportError will be given and you can install the package.

```
import pip
import imp

try:
    imp.find_module(package)
except ImportError:
    pip.main(['install', package])
```

Comment: How can I do this if I do not want to import it? Can I Just throw it out?

Comment: That is very difficult (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668223/how-to-de-import-a-python-module). At least you could remove the import after the exception as this is not required. I have modified the answer to use imp to check if the module is available which does not actually import the module

Answer (score -3):

you should use this

```
import pip
import sys

def install(package):
    if not package in sys.modules:
        pip.main(['install', package])
# Example
if __name__ == '__main__':
    install('argh')
```

Comment: `if package` just tests whether `package` isn't an empty string - why?