# How to undo effects of `import readline`?

Tags: python, readline

Adding `import readline` to the source code affects builtin functions (like `input()` and `raw_input()`) enabling GNU readline, history and all that arrow stuff. I wonder, is there any way to undo it?

P.S. "Solutions" like `del readline` and `from __builtins__ import raw_input` don't work. You can try `python2 -c "raw_input(); import readline; raw_input(); del readline; raw_input()"` to check it.

Comment: Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668223/how-to-de-import-a-python-module?answertab=active#tab-top) ?

Comment: @fn. yes. Doesn't help too. I guess, your solution is more about delete a name from a namespace than about undoing side effects of import.

Comment: How is `import readline` affecting your built in functions? Anything imported should be directly under `readline` like `readline.input()`? Unless you did something like `from readline import *` [which is the source your headache](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).

Comment: @ldlehands importing readline does enable command line editing using GNU readline.

Remember, whole module is executed/evaluated when you import it.